# Android Studio - Broken pipe

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-girafee

Broken pipe.

The Gradle daemon may be trying to use ipv4 instead of ipv6.

Currently I use : Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4
Previously I downloaded Studio Hedgehog, but I switched back to Giraffe.

Do you know what's the issue?

Comment: Can you show your gradle version, and in general more logs than now?

Comment: The Gradle daemon may be trying to use ipv4 instead of ipv6.

<a href="open.more.details">More info (including workarounds)</a>
2024-01-03 12:54:44,043 [ 737703]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
2024-01-03 12:54:44,043 [ 737703]   INFO - #o.j.k.i.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] IllegalStateException loading gradle script templates: Unable to get Gradle home directory